# How to convert type to class with typescript compiler api

Tags: typescript

I want to convert a type to a class with 'class-validator' Declaration;
as :

```
    type a = {
      aa: string,
      bb: number,
    }
```

to

```
    class a {
      @IsString()
      aa: string
      @IsNumber()
      bb:number
    }
```

I think that i should visit typeNode of *type a*.But i don't know how to do it.
or is there any better method .

Comment: Check this: https://ts-ast-viewer.com/#code/C4TwDgpgBAhlC8UDeAoK7YwFxQM7ACcBLAOwHMAaNDAIxpxIFcBbGiAqgXxRQGMAbGLlyxk1dAAEAkrgDKhUmQAUASnGYc+YuXXTcAORZsCq9XQZH2KTkA

Comment: this is really useful.but how can i visit type a ?@Jean-Alphonse