# how to convert class to type in typescript?

Tags: typescript, class, generics, types, type-conversion

I need to use class as generic parameter so need to convert class to type.

I have,

```
class SomeClass{
  public member1: string;
  private member2: string;
  protected member3: string;

  private method1 (){ }     
}
```

I need,

```
type SomeClassType = {
  member1: string;
  member2: string;
  member3: string;
  method1: () => void;
}
```

I tried,

```
type T1 = typeof ClassConstructor<SomeClass>;
type T2 = typeof SomeClass;
type T3 = keyof typeof SomeClass;

const v1: T1; // v1.member1 doesn't work
const v2: T2; // v2.member1 doesn't work
const v3: T3; // v3.member1 doesn't work
```

I saw,

- [How to convert type to class with typescript compiler api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69111512/how-to-convert-type-to-class-with-typescript-compiler-api)
- [Convert the Normal class to generic in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72617572/convert-the-normal-class-to-generic-in-typescript)

Comment: I don't understand the question. Classes *are* types `class Foo {}` will define a run-time construct *and* a compile-time type. Moreover, you say you want to use it as a generic parameter, which is already possible, e.g., `Array<SomeClass>`. Finally, the block of code you said you tried makes no real sense: why would you try to "access a property" on a type? That's not a code that would ever work. Types aren't values.

Comment: "you say you want to use it as a generic parameter, which is already possible" => you are right. I misunderstood.
"why would you try to "access a property" on a type? " => thank you. I fixed.

Comment: The code still doesn't make sense. All you need is `type T4 = SomeClass` which is literally then like using `const v4: SomeClass`. And it allows you to use `v4.member1` as that's a property that the class has declared. Why are you jumping through so many hoops when all I get from the question is that you have `class SomeClass` and you want to use `SomeClass`. What *doesn't work* when you do that? Why try to do anything else?